# Chatbot that lets users order coffee

Tags: javascript

**Note:** In order to keep this post somewhat short, I have moved some data from the database to the client-side. An example hereof is the prices object.

This is a simple program/chatbot which users can use to order coffee. The code is working just fine, but it's very messy. I am looking for ways to clean up the code, to make it more understandable for other developers. I am, also sure there are code duplications that could be moved to functions, but having worked on this for a while I became blind to my own mistakes. Any help is welcome.

```
const chat = document.getElementById("chat");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const state = document.getElementById("state");
const response = document.getElementById("response");
const langSelector = document.getElementById("lang-selector");

const appState = {
  language: "en",
  requestedSize: false,
  currentDrink: {},
  order: { drinks: [], price: 0 }
};

const prices = {
  caffeAmericano: { short: 2.25, tall: 2.45, grande: 2.95 },
  caffèLatte: { short: 2.95, tall: 3.65, grande: 4.15 },
  caffèMocha: { short: 3.45, tall: 4.15, grande: 4.65 },
  cappuccino: { short: 3.15, tall: 3.25, grande: 3.95 },
  caramelMacchiato: { short: 3.75, tall: 4.45, grande: 4.75 },
  espresso: { short: 1.95, tall: 2.25, grande: 2.65 },
  espressoConPanna: { short: 1.95, tall: 2.25, grande: 2.65 },
  espressoMacchiato: { short: 1.95, tall: 2.25, grande: 2.65 },
  whiteChocolateMocha: { short: 3.75, tall: 4.45, grande: 4.75 }
};

function calculateTotalOrderPrice() {
  return parseFloat(
    appState.order.drinks.reduce((price, drink) => price + drink.price, 0).toFixed(2)
  );
}

function resetState() {
  appState.requestedSize = false;
  appState.currentDrink = {};
  appState.order = { drinks: [], price: 0 };
}

function calculateDrinkPrice({ name, size, amount }) {
  const price = prices[name][size] * amount;
  return Math.round(price * 100) / 100;
}

function postMessage(message, isResponse = true) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  isResponse && li.classList.add("left");
  li.innerHTML = message;
  chat.appendChild(li);
}

function generateOrderStatusMessage() {
  let message = "";

  if (appState.language === "en") {
    message = "Here is what I have for your order.<br>";
    appState.order.drinks.forEach(d => (message += `<br>- ${d.amount}x ${d.size} ${d.name}`));
    message += `<br><br>For a total of: $${appState.order.price}`;
    message += `<button>Place order</button>`;
  } else if (appState.language === "nl") {
    message = "Hier is wat ik heb voor uw bestelling.<br>";
    appState.order.drinks.forEach(d => (message += `<br>- ${d.amount}x ${d.size} ${d.name}`));
    message += `<br><br>Voor een totaal van: $${appState.order.price}`;
    message += `<button>Plaats bestelling</button>`;
  }

  return message;
}

function addDrinkToOrder(drink) {
  appState.currentDrink = {};
  appState.order.drinks.push(drink);
  appState.order.price = calculateTotalOrderPrice();
  postMessage(generateOrderStatusMessage());
}

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (input.value) {
    postMessage(input.value, false);
    fetch(`/api/${appState.language}/${input.value.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase()}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        if (json.intent === "Order.Reset") {
          resetState();
          postMessage(json.answer);
        } else if (json.intent === "Order.Size" && appState.requestedSize) {
          const drink = appState.currentDrink;
          const { resolution, option } = json.entities.find(entity => entity.entity === "size");

          drink.size = resolution ? resolution.value : option;

          if (drink.name && drink.size && drink.amount) {
            drink.price = calculateDrinkPrice(drink);
          }

          appState.requestedSize = false;
          addDrinkToOrder(drink);
        } else if (json.intent === "Order") {
          const drink = { name: "", size: "", amount: 1, price: 0 };

          json.entities.forEach(({ entity, resolution, option }) => {
            const value = resolution ? resolution.value : option;

            switch (entity) {
              case "drink":
                drink.name = value;
                break;
              case "number":
                drink.amount = value;
                break;
              case "size":
                drink.size = value;
                break;
            }

            if (drink.name && drink.size && drink.amount) {
              drink.price = calculateDrinkPrice(drink);
            }
          });

          if (drink.size !== "") {
            appState.requestedSize = false;
            addDrinkToOrder(drink);
          } else {
            appState.requestedSize = true;
            appState.currentDrink = drink;
            if (appState.language === "en") {
              postMessage(`What size "${drink.name}" would you like?`);
            } else if (appState.language === "nl") {
              postMessage(`Welke maat "${drink.name}" wilt u?`);
            }
          }
        } else {
          postMessage(json.answer);
        }

        chat.scroll({ top: chat.scrollHeight - chat.clientHeight, behavior: "smooth" });
        state.textContent = JSON.stringify(appState, null, 2);
        response.textContent = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
      });

    input.value = "";
  }
});

function changeLanguage() {
  resetState();
  chat.innerHTML = "";
  appState.language = langSelector.value;
  state.textContent = JSON.stringify(appState, null, 2);
  appState.language === "en"
    ? postMessage(`Welcome to <strong>Coffee Bot</strong>, how can I help you?`)
    : postMessage(`Welkom bij <strong>Coffee Bot</strong>, hoe kan ik u helpen?`);
}

langSelector.addEventListener("change", changeLanguage);

changeLanguage();
```

Comment: I suggest a few changes, the language logic very much feels like it should be in a separate object of some sort so you can easier to maintain the languages. At the minute you're doing an if/elseif all over the place and it's very quickly going to become unmaintainable. Also if you do expand to letting others submit/revise languages having one place to edit will save you a lot of time.
`const dictionary = { welcome: { en: 'Welcome to <strong>Coffee Bot</strong>, how can I help you?', nl: 'Welkom bij <strong>Coffee Bot</strong>, hoe kan ik u helpen?'}, askSize: { en: ...., nl: ....}}`

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time in original comment for more suggestions so I've had to split it up.
I also think you're doing too much logic in the closure for the submit button. You might want to consider having it just do the validation that you've input something, and then hand off to another function to hit the API and handle the responses. Named functions are supposed to have a single clear purpose and this will help you spot when you're doing too many things in a single function.